# xwindow and poor man's video wall

Tags: linux

We have a "video wall" at my workplace. It consists of 8 43" - 50" screens. 5 of them support full HD resolution, remaining 3, do not. Screens also have different video inputs. Some support HDMI and DVI, while other have only VGA input.

Currently we have 4 PC's running those screens. This solution is cumbersome because of the number of keyboards and mouses necessary to operate this mess. What is more, since there are 4 PC's, there are 4 different desktops. Some services can be lunched only on PC's with certain IP address.

I would like to build a PC, that would be able to run all those 8 screens as single desktop and support 2D/3D hardware acceleration.

Since it's poor man's video wall consisting of screens that have different inputs and resolutions, we can NOT use Matrox M9188 PCIe x16.

I was thinking about purchasing a 4 - 5 PCI Express motherboard for example:
ASUS P9D WS 1150

and 4 cheap graphic cards:
GeForce GT 630

That would give me 4 HDMI, 4 DVI and 4 VGA to connect all my screens and more.

Since i never build anything like that before I would like to ask you the following:

- Doest it make sense ? xD
- Is it possible to create desktop so big ~(7680x2160)
- Will it support 2D/3D acceleration despite the fact that those graphics cards do not have SLI

Thank you for your help !

Comment: what is "CRT input"? Why are you not using Synergy to control all computers from one?

Comment: Why is this tagged linux?

Comment: @Mxx, My apologies, I meant VGA, not CRT. I am already using Synergy. What I need is single desktop, so I could move entire windows across whole 8 screen desktop.

Comment: @Pretzel, Because I want to run Linux on this machine.